# Problems with PHP SQL Registration form

Tags: php, sql, database, registration

as the title suggests i'm creating a registration form using PHP and SQL.  Whenever I click the register button, I get an undefined variable error on ALL of the variables in the form, also nothing is entered in the database. Please if youcan suggest anything, i'm pulling my hair out.

Here is the page that the form submits to:

```
<?php
include('dbconfig.php');
?>

<?php

 echo $_GET["FirstName"]; 
?>

<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase;', 'root', '');

$firstname = $_POST['FirstName'];
$lastname  = $_POST['LastName'];
$username  = $_POST['username' ];
$password  = $_POST['Password'];
$email     = $_POST['Email'];
$startdate = $_POST['StartDate'];
$year      = $_POST['Year'];



$password = md5($password);



$sql = "INSERT into supervisor (FirstName, LastName, UserName, Password, Email,                      
Company) VALUES (:FirstName, :LastName, :UserName, :Password, :Email)";

$statement = $db->prepare($sql);

$params = array(
':FirstName' => $firstname,
':LastName'  => $lastname, 
':Password'  => $password,
':Email'     => $email,
':StartDate' => $startdate,
':Year'      => $year,
':Company'   => $company
);
```

The dbconfig file:

```
<?php

$config['db'] = array(
'host'      => 'localhost',
'username'  => 'root',
'password'  =>  '',
'dbname'    =>  'mydatabase',

);

$db = new PDO('mysql:host='. $config['db']['host'] .';dbname='. $config['db']
['dbname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);


?>
```

Finally the registration php file (just the form):

```
<div class="container">   
  <form id="regform" class="form-signin" action='staffRegister.php' method='Post'    
 onsubmit="return validateForm()"/>
     <img src="logo.png" width="160" height="50"> <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Staff       

Registration</h2>


        <div>
            <label for="name">First Name: </label>
            <input id="fname" name="name" type="text" class="input-                             

block-level" maxlength="35" onFocus="if(this.value=='name')this.value='';" onblur =   
"checkField(this)"/>
            <span id="Alpha"  style="display:none;">Please use letters  

only.</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Last Name: </label>
            <input id="lname" name="name" type="text" class="input- 

block-level" maxlength="35" onFocus="if(this.value=='name')this.value='';" onblur = 

"checkField1(this)"/>
            <span id="Alpha2"  style="display:none;">Please use letters 

only.</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="name">UserName: </label>
            <input id="username" name="name" type="text" class="input-

block-level" maxlength="12"  />

        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">E-mail Ad:</label>
            <input id="email" placeholder="@kent.ac.uk"name="Email" 
type="text" class="input-block-level" onchange="return validateEmail();"/></br>
            <span id="spanEmail"  style="display:none;">Please use your    
Kent Email.</span>

        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="pass1">Password:</label>
            <input id="pass1" name="pass1" type="password"   
class="input-block-level" maxlength="12" />
            <span id="pass1Info">At least 6 characters: letters,  
numbers and '_'</span>
        </div>
        <div>





    <center><input type='Submit' name='Submit' value="Register" class="btn btn-   
 primary"/ >    </input></center>
  </form>
```

Any help really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why not just bind to the `POST`ed variables?

Answer (score 0):

The names in your HTMl do not correspond to the keys you're using in `$_POST`. You're posting both Firstname and Surname with a name of `name` and trying to fetch them with `$_POST['FirstName']` `$_POST['LastName']` respectively.

Comment: Are you definitely posting to the correct script? If so, what happens when you `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: Yes, the variables all post correctly now, however, the data is still not present in the database

Comment: That would seem to be a completely different issue. I'm guessing you haven't posted all of your code for that, as you're not actually executing your prepared statement.

Comment: This is all the code I have... (bar some html and javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 problems.

1.Mixing `$_GET[]` and `$_POST[]`. as `form method = post` use `$_POST[]`

2.Naming of variable between form and php. ie `fname` in form and `$firstname` in php. Also the name and id of the text inputs should be the same.

3.The warnings you are getting appears when your variable are not properly set,. To resolve this use [**isset()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). The code below illustrates the problem.(save as post.php)

```
<?php 
echo "Test for $_POST & isset()<br>";
$test1 = isset($_POST['test1']) ? $_POST['test1'] : ''; 
$test2 = $_POST['test2'];
echo $test1;
echo "<br>";
echo $test2;
?> 
<form action="post.php" method="post"> 
<input name="test1" type="checkbox" value="1"> 
<input name="test2" type="checkbox" value="2"> 
<input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

The above demo uses isset() and the [**ternary operator**](http://phpmaster.com/using-the-ternary-operator/) and I have illustrated how to utilise it in your code.

```
$fname = isset($_POST['$fname']) ? $_POST['$f'] : ''; 
$lname = isset($_POST['$lname']) ? $_POST['$lname'] : ''; 
etc
```